# I need a hint to start on this programming puzzle

Tags: php, algorithm, tree

You have a room-full of balances and weights. Each balance weighs ten pounds and is considered perfectly balanced when the sum of weights on its left and right sides are exactly the same. You have placed some weights on some of the balances, and you have placed some of the balances on other balances. Given a description of how the balances are arranged and how much additional weight is on each balance, determine how to add weight to the balances so that they are all perfectly balanced.

There may be more than one way to balance everything, but always choose the way that places additional weight on the lowest balances.

The input file will begin with a single integer, N, specifying how many balances there are.
Balance 0 is specified by lines 1 and 2, balance 1 is specified by lines 3 and 4, etc...
Each pair of lines is formatted as follows:

```
WL <balances>
WR <balances>
```

WL and WR indicate the weight added to the left and right sides, respectively.  is a space-delimited list of the other balance that are on that side of this balance.  may contain zero or more elements.

Consider the following input:

```
4
0 1
0 2
0
0 3
3
0
0
0

Balance 0 has balance 1 on its left side and balance 2 on its right side
Balance 1 has balance 3 on its right side
Balance 2 has three pounds on its left side
Balance 3 has nothing on it
```

Since balance 3 has nothing on it it is already perfectly balanced, and weighs a total of 10 pounds.
Balance 2 has no other balance on it, so all we need to do is balance it by putting three pounds on its right side. Now it weighs a total of 16 pounds.
Balance 1 has balance three on its right side, which weighs 10 pounds, so we just put 10 pounds on its left side. Balance 1 weighs a total of 30 pounds.
Balance 0 has balance 1 on its left side (30 pounds), and balance 2 on its right side (16 pounds), we can balance it by adding 14 pounds to the right side.

The output should be N lines long, with the nth line listing the weight added to the nth balance, formatted as follows:

```
<index>: <weight added to left side> <weight added to right side>
```

So the output for this problem would be:

```
0: 0 14
1: 10 0
2: 0 3
3: 0 0
```

I tried but I'm really bad at programming I guess. Where should I start? please don't post the solution; I want to learn.

Comment: @Adam: Think about modelling what's going on as a tree structure, where each balance is a branch node and each weight is a leaf.

Comment: Incidentally, I think this is an interesting question that ought to be reopened - a couple of other people seem to agree with me as well.

Comment: i vote for reopening this one, this is very interesting question

Comment: i want to know the answer

Comment: This is a very interesting problem, i vote for reopening

Comment: seirously? this post as 9 vote up, lots of comments about re-open it, what would it take to re-open it?

Comment: Facebook interview question apprently

Comment: This should be re-open

Comment: There is nothing or a mix of balance(s) and some weight on either side - the problem would be more interesting (GCJ grade ;-) if either side has only: nothing, a weight xor a balance. The problem as it is can be solved easily: start from B0, recursively solve all balances on L and R. When you reach a balance with no balance on either side, the recursive func returns 10+WL+WR (balanced). Below, the balance has got all its balances solved on L and R, so its current weight is 10 + WL + ∑(balances)L + WR + ∑(balances)R. Balance that adding a weight on L or R if necessary and return the new sum.

Answer (score 1):

This is your tree

```
           (0)
     -------------      
     |           | 
    (2)         (1)
 ---------    -------   
 |       |    |     |
[3p]     ..   ..   (3)
                  ------
                  |     |
                 ...    ..
```

Your logic should create this tree in the memory with every node containing the following data structure.

```
BalanceIdx: Integer;    //The balance index number if any. -1 indicates none
InitialPounds: Integer; //Initial weight in the node 
AddedPounds: Integer;   //The weight you added when processing. Default is 0
TotalWeight: Integer;   //**Total weight of a node including all its children. This is also our indication that a particular branch is already traversed. Default is -1
```

We are talking about a recursive function which basically knows that it has only two paths or no path to follow when in any node of the tree. Each recursion is considered sitting on a plate of a balance.

Here is the logic.

1. Start from the root and travel until you find a node which has no path to go from.
2. Update the `TotalWeight` of it with the help of it's `InitialPounds`.
3. Now see if the node's other sibling has it's `TotalWeight`set. If **NO**, set the root of your recursive function there and execute.
4. If **YES**, calculate the difference and update the `AddedPounds` of where you sit. Now go to the parent and update its `TotalWeight`. (don't forget to add 10p for the balance(s)). Then go to the grand parent and repeat 3.

Once the recursive function completes traversing the whole tree, you have `AddedPounds` recorded in each node. Use another recursive function to construct the output.

This answer is for a starter which you have asked for.

Comment: Each balance needs to point to a left-child and a right-child.  And doesn't need to store its *own* Idx.  Also, you probably want to store left and right AddedPounds separately, unless you want to handle added weights with a dummy balance.  Also, InitialPounds and TotalWeight could be local vars in your recursive function, rather than stored in your data structure.  Also, you have no provisions for handling multiple balances on the same pan, but I guess you left that out intentionally since the OP only asked for a start (4 years ago :P)

Comment: Each recursion is not considered to have been sitting on the root of a balance - but on a plate of a balance. 1.Please note I have  said that *"We are talking about a recursive function which basically knows that it has only two paths or no path to follow when in any node of the tree"*. The BalanceIdx is used as an indication to show if this "plate" has a child balance hanging in there.  2. InitialPounds and TotalWeight cannot be local variables since former is part of the output and the latter is your direct output which you will accumulate at the end. Thanks for the review.

Comment: Have a look at my answer.  I total up the weights of sub-trees in local variables by having my recursive function return the weight of that balance (10lb) plus everything on its pans (after adjustment).  Using recursive functions lets you use locals this way.  You couldn't if you were doing an iterative traversal of the tree without recursion, but recursion gives you a separate instance of the locals for each subtree.  Anyway, I guess you're saying there's a separate data structure to represent a balance?  Like `struct balance { struct pan left, right; }`?  BalanceIdx indexes an array of that?

Answer (score 1):

#### SPOILER ALERT:  Full solution included (except for reading the input)

This question is quite old, and looked fun, so I just went and solved it (in C, not PHP like this is tagged), after a few hint-like opening paragraphs.  I used verbose variable names and commented, so it should work as pseudocode.  I *was* going to write C-like pseudocode, but never hit anything that was worth summarizing.

---

The main complication to this problem is that you can't use **binary** trees, because a single balance can have multiple other balances on either or both of its pans.  Probably the easiest approach here is linked-lists of nodes, where each node has left and right children, and also a sibling pointer.  To get all the balances sitting on the left pan of a balance,  the traverse the linked list of sibling pointers starting with the left child of the node for the balance you're looking at.

Since the input format assigns numbers to all the balances, it's easiest to just use those indices into an array of structs.  If you can assume there are less than 2^31 balances, you can save memory by using 32bit ints instead of 64bit pointers.  (Negative indices are a sentinel for empty, like a NULL pointer in pointer-based tree/list implementations)

```
struct balance {
    // weights sitting directly on the pans of this balance
    float weight_left, weight_right;  // or unsigned int; the question only said the balance-count was an int.  I assumed the balance-IDs were int, too

    // optionally: float adjustment;  // For recording our changes.  negative or positive for adding to left or right balance.

    // references to other balances: negative means empty-list, otherwise index into an array.
    int next;           // linked-list of sibling balances on the same pan of a parent
    int left, right;    // list-heads for balances on the left and right pan
};
```

When they say you should add weight to the "lowest" balance, I guess they mean the root is at the bottom.  It's not a tree of hanging balances suspended from something.

You're allowed to add weights to balances that are already carrying balances.  So there's no complication about adding weight to empty pans at leaves of the tree.  (That would require dividing the weight in a way that kept every subtree balanced individually).

So this looks quite simple to solve recursively.

- A subtree can be balanced on its own, without any information about any other balances.
- It doesn't matter what combination of weights and other balances makes up the load on the left and right pans.  You just need those two totals.  Balance by adding weight directly to the lighter pan.
- Balance a balance *after* balancing the all its sub sub-trees.  You can total up the weights of the sub-trees while balancing them.

So the algorithm is:

```
static const float BALANCE_WEIGHT = 10.0f;

// return total weight of the balance and everything on it, including the 10.0f that this balance weighs
// modify the .weight_left or .weight_right of every node that needs it, in the subtrees of this node
float balance(struct balance storage[], int current)
{
    float lweight = 0, rweight = 0;

    // C++ can make this more readable:
    // struct balance &cur = storage[current];

    // loop over all the left and then right children, totalling them up
    // depth-first search, since we recurse/descend before doing anything else with the current
    for (int i = storage[current].left ; i >= 0 ; i = storage[i].next )
        lweight += balance(storage, i);

    for (int i = storage[current].right; i >= 0 ; i = storage[i].next )
        rweight += balance(storage, i);


    lweight += storage[current].weight_left;
    rweight += storage[current].weight_right;

    float correction = fabsf(rweight - lweight);

    // modify the data structure in-place with the correction.
    // TODO: print, or add to some other data structure to record the changes
    if (lweight < rweight) {
        storage[current].weight_left += correction;
    } else {
        storage[current].weight_right += correction;
    }

    return BALANCE_WEIGHT + rweight + lweight + correction;
}
```

To record what changes you made, either use an extra field in the data structure, or destroy the original data as you come back up from the depth-first balancing (since it's no longer needed).  e.g. store `.weight_left = correction; .weight_right = 0;` if the left needs weight added, otherwise do the reverse.

---

This implementation would use less stack space if there was a global array, instead of each recursive call having to pass the `storage` pointer around.  That's an extra value that has to get saved/restored in a register-call ABI, and directly takes up extra space in a stack-call ABI like 32bit x86.

All the calculations involving the current node's `weight_left` and `weight_right` happen at the end, rather than reading them at the start and then having to re-read them for the += read-modify-write.  A compiler couldn't make this optimization, because it can't know that the data structure doesn't have cycles, causing `balance(subtree)` to modify one of those weights.

For some reason, x86 gcc 5.2 `-O3` [compiles this to really huge code](http://goo.gl/ah4n2G).  It's more sane with `-O2`.  `clang` does ok with `-O3`, but misses some optimizations.

Comment: Good remark that this is not a binary tree problem. I missed that first because of the (too) simple example given by the Asker.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will also give working code, this time in PHP.

Some important observations:

- Even though the given example never puts more than one balance on either side of any of the balances, multiple balances are allowed to sit on one side of a balance;
- There is no guarantee that there is only one root balance, there could be several detached stacks in the room;
- The input format would allow for one balance to rest on multiple other balances, or to rest multiple times on the same balance side, or even rest on itself. It is assumed that such and other cyclic input would be considered invalid;
- The condition *"choose the way that places additional weight on the lowest balances"* is equivalent to saying *"you are allowed to add a weight on one side of each balance only, never both"*

Four functions are defined:

- **parseInput** takes an input string an returns an array of objects representing the data in a logical way;
- **addWeights** takes the index (ID) of a balance and calculates on which side of it weight should be added, and stores that weight in a new property. The calculation uses recursion to calculate the weight of all the balances resting on either side of this balance, after these have been balanced with added weights. It throws an error if cycles are detected, so also preventing endless recursion;
- **balance** visits all balances, and if they have not been balanced yet, a call to the above *addWeights* is made. This will cover multiple *root* balance configurations;
- **outputString** takes the completed structure and returns a string in the expected output format.

The data structure is an array of pairs of objects. The example data would be transformed to the following, with the *addedWeight* property added during the calculations:

```
[
  [
    { 'weight' => 0, 'balances' => [1], 'addedWeight' =>  0 },
    { 'weight' => 0, 'balances' => [2], 'addedWeight' => 14 }
  ], [
    { 'weight' => 0, 'balances' =>  [], 'addedWeight' => 10 },
    { 'weight' => 0, 'balances' => [3], 'addedWeight' =>  0 }
  ], [
    { 'weight' => 3, 'balances' =>  [], 'addedWeight' =>  0 },
    { 'weight' => 0, 'balances' =>  [], 'addedWeight' =>  3 }
  ], [
    { 'weight' => 0, 'balances' =>  [], 'addedWeight' =>  0 },
    { 'weight' => 0, 'balances' =>  [], 'addedWeight' =>  0 }
  ]
]
```

Comments in the code should explain the most important parts:

```
function parseInput($input) {
    $lines = preg_split('/(\r\n|\n)/', $input, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $count = (int) array_shift($lines); // we don't need this item
    $balances = array();
    $side = array();
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        // get the numbers from one line in an array of numbers
        $args = array_map('intval', explode(' ', $line));
        $obj = new stdClass();
        // first number represents the weight
        $obj->weight = array_shift($args);
        // all other numbers represent IDs of balances
        $obj->balances = $args;
        // collect this as a side, next iteration will fill other side
        $side[] = $obj;
        if (count($side) == 2) {
            // after each two lines, add the two objects to main array
            $balances[] = $side;
            $side = array();
        }
    }
    return $balances;
}

function addWeights(&$balances, $id) {
    if ($id == -1) {
        // There is no balance here: return 0 weight
        return 0;
    }
    // Check that structure is not cyclic:
    if (isset($balances[$id][0]->addedWeight)) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid balance structure: #$id re-encountered");;
    }
    $total = 10; // weight of balance itself
    $added = 0;
    foreach($balances[$id] as &$side) {
        // get the direct weight put in the balance: 
        $weight = $side->weight;
        // add to it the total weight of any balances on this side,
        // by using recursion
        foreach($side->balances as $balanceId) {
            $weight += addWeights($balances, $balanceId);
        }
        // calculate difference in left/right total weight
        $added = $weight - $added;
        $total += $weight;
        // create new property with result
        $side->addedWeight = 0;
    }
    // set either left or right added weight:
    $balances[$id][$added > 0 ? 0 : 1]->addedWeight = abs($added);
    $total += abs($added);
    return $total;
}

function balance(&$balances) {
    // If the only root balance was at index 0, we could just 
    // call addWeights($balances, 0), but it might be elsewhere
    // and there might even be multiple roots:
    foreach($balances as $index => $balance) {
        if (!isset($balance[0]->addedWeight)) {
            addWeights($balances, $index);
        }
    }
}

function outputString(&$balances) {
    $output = '';
    foreach($balances as $index => $balance) {
        $output .= "$index: {$balance[0]->addedWeight} {$balance[1]->addedWeight}\n";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Here is how it is used:

```
// test data
$input =
"4
0 1
0 2
0
0 3
3
0
0
0";
// 1. transform input into structure
$balances = parseInput($input);
// 2. main algorithm
balance($balances);
// 3. output the result in desired format
echo outputString($balances);
```

Output is:

```
0: 0 14
1: 10 0
2: 0 3
3: 0 0
```

Comment: Well spotted that the question didn't say there had to be a single root.  I didn't even realize I was making that assumption!

Comment: Thanks, @PeterCordes, I wrote some more stuff and added a check to prevent running into tree cycles. We both know this is pure for fun, as the question dates from 2011, but the fun is in the doing not in the reward.

Comment: Yup, I had my fun making my solution efficient: Showing that unlike some more clumsy solutions, you can keep track of the added masses on the fly, as return values / locals in the recursion.  You only need to add anything to the data structure to print it out in a different order from the traversal.  Although the multi-root part of the "room full of balances" problem might require a revision to that.  IDK if I'll bother, though.

Comment: Indeed, the on-the-fly total weight calculation is nice. The multi-root support is easily implemented in your code: you just need to keep track of visited nodes (e.g. as an additional boolean in the struct). Then instead of calling *balance* once with index 0 in your main, go through the whole array, and call *balance* on any elements that were not visited yet (these are the additional roots). Could be optimised by maintaining a double linked list of non-visited nodes, but I didn't go for that.

Comment: Great solution, 
Can i have a solution in python.

Comment: @AkshayKumarBoth, sure this can work in Python. Did you try it? If you have a particular problem with coding in Python, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

### Overview

The problem requires a tree structure to represent balances which are resting on balances.  In order to solve the problem, you need to be able to:-

1. Find all the balances.  That requires some form of recursive function where you can visit left and right children.
2. Counting the weights.  From a given balance, find out the weight on its left side, and on its right side.
3. Adding weights.  Given that the question states that the weights need to be added to the lowest balances first, then you repeatedly look through the trees for a balance which has no children, or has children which have already been balanced.